# How to get Instagram story poll results (i.e. the percentages)?

Tags: instagram-api

For my project I need to somehow query the Instagram API and get, how many people have voted/the percentages of each option. Aka something like this:

```
[
   {
      "text": "Option A",
      "votes": 123
   },
   {
      "text": "Option B",
      "votes": 456
   }
]
```

Or this:

```
[
   {
      "text": "Option A",
      "percentage": 5
   },
   {
      "text": "Option B",
      "percentage": 95
   }
]
```

I've looked everywhere but I can't find even a mention of this functionality even tho I've found a way to get a list of people, who have voted.